# Does PhoneGap use just UIWebVIew or is it doing something more then that? Nitro?

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, cordova, titanium

Does PhoneGap just use UIWebVIew or is it doing something more then that?

Can it take advantage of Apples Nitro VM?

I'm currently exploring the choices for porting our javascript app to native. I'm researching PhoneGap and Titanium, trying to figure out how they differ.

Thanks for any insight.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes PhoneGap uses a UIWebView but it is highly customized with lots of custom javascript which gets injected into the page.

No as it uses a UIWebView it doesn't gets to use the NITRO javascript engine.

Edit: Apple corrected the fullscreen web apps bug however they did not fix it for UIWebViews as that would let normal apps mark memory chunks as executable (security risk).

Comment: Thanks! Have you worked with Titanium at all, is it doing the same thing?

Comment: @oolong Yes I tried out Titanium briefly. No Titanium is not using a UIWebView, Titanium doesn't even use the code you give it. It converts/compiles your js code into Objective-C & then lets Xcode compile that Objective-C into fully native arm code.

Comment: @oolong With PhoneGap you write a WebApp which has access to some native features through javascript. With Titanium you write a native app using javascript rather then obj-c.

Comment: Find me some documentation to the contrary, but I have found no evidence that UIWebViews in applications make use of Nitro.  http://www.quora.com/iOS-5/Did-UIWebView-in-iOS-5-get-the-Nitro-JavaScript-engine

Comment: @jamie yes sorry, apple fixed the bug where full screen web apps didn't use it. However they can't enable it for UIWebViews without either creating a big security risk or splitting Javascript rendering into a separate process.

Comment: So that would be "No, it does not use Nitro" then.

Comment: i pray nitro lands on webviews in ios6...not holding my breath tho.

Comment: Freerunnering - just to amend the record, Titanium doesn't compile your code into Objective-C. Instead it runs the built in javascript engine (outside of UIWebView), and has an interface from the JS to Objective-C modules. See http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2012/05/comparing-titanium-and-phonegap.html

Comment: It seems like there's a way to enable Nitro by changing the application entitlements in XCode. See [link](www.littlereddoor.co.uk/ios/how-to-enable-the-nitro-javascript-engine-in-ios-applications-directly-through-xcode/)

Answer (score 0):

In Titanium, app code is written in core JavaScript and it spits native code while compilation using language bridge. So Titanium is completely native.

PhoneGap is nothing but just a UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to know too. I have found no evidence that Nitro is enabled in UIWebView. There is plenty of evidence that it was *not* enabled in 4.3 (it was only in Safari itself). There are reports that it was enabled in other Apps beyond Safari in 5.0, but I can find no evidence that it is enabled in UIWebView.

From [CNET](http://news.cnet.com/8301-30685_3-20071897-264/ios-5-could-fix-some-slow-web-apps/) referencing the [HN](http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2661974) discussion:

> "There's also a way to create Web apps on iOS that doesn't use Safari
>   proper, an interface called UIWebView.
>
> That doesn't look to be getting the Nitro speed-up for security
>   reasons involving just-in-time (JIT) compilation that Nitro uses to
>   create faster versions of JavaScript software on the fly."

More reading:

- http://daringfireball.net/2011/03/nitro_ios_43
- http://www.quora.com/iOS-5/Did-UIWebView-in-iOS-5-get-the-Nitro-JavaScript-engine